# sprintf() assigning garbage values

Tags: c++

I have the below code which copies the ID from m_InfoStruct to temp_ID and then to final_ID. The issue is that when m_InfoStruct->ID is less than 10 digits (which in my case is 6 digits), sometimes, the remaining 4 bytes will have garbage values stored in it (even though the first 6 digits will have the actual ID copied from the structure).
This seems to be happening at random and I am not able to see this issue when debugging. Is there a way to copy only the data from m_InfoStruct->ID and keep the remaining bytes as blank.

I am not sure if the garbage data is being stored when copying the data from m_InfoStruct->ID to tempID using sprintf or when copying the data from tempID to final_ID.

PS: For multiple other reasons, I cannot change the data type or length of any of these variables.

```
char tempID[10];
AsciiArray<10> final_ID;

sprintf(temp_ID, "");
sprintf (temp_ID, "%d", m_InfoStruct->ID);   //Here m_InfoStruct->ID is unsigned long
final_ID = "";
final_ID.Copy (temp_ID, 0, 10);
m_info.SetCID (final_ID);
```

Comment: `%d` is the wrong format string for an `unsigned long`. Use `%lu` instead.

Comment: In general, you should better use ```snprintf``` instead of ```sprintf``` in order to have a better control of memory usage.

Comment: The format `%d` is for `int`. The type `unsigned long` needs the format `%lu`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. As a solution, stop using unsafe C functions when programming in C++. Use the C++ functions and classes, like `std::string` and `std::to_string`.

Comment: Also note that the big compilers are able to detect such mismatch as you have and warn about it. If you don't get a warning then enable more warnings and treat them as errors.

Comment: Not harmful, but `sprintf(temp_ID, "");` and possibly `final_ID = "";` seem pointless since they are immediately overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. (The problem you reported) `sprintf` leaving garbage in the buffer is *normal*; it has no idea how large the buffer is, so all it can do is print exactly as much as the data you give it demands, plus a single `NUL` terminator. If your 10 char buffer wasn't initialized to zeroes, and you printed a number that requires six digits, it will write six digits, a `NUL`, and leave the final three digits untouched. If you don't want that, zero the buffer first, either by initializing it properly, or by zeroing it before use (e.g. `memset(temp_id, '\0', 10)`; you could use the return value of `sprintf` to determine where, and how much, to zero after the fact, but that's premature optimization for zeroing such a small amount of data). `sprintf(temp_ID, "")` is thoroughly useless here (it writes the single `NUL`, and nothing else, and that `NUL` gets overridden an instant later by the second `sprintf`).
2. (The problem you didn't notice) You're using the wrong format code. If your value is an `unsigned long`, use `%lu`, not `%d`, you're invoking undefined behavior by failing to do so (as it happens, for values that fit in an `int`, on a little-endian system and *some* big-endian systems, it will often work, but there are *zero* guarantees)
3. (Another problem waiting to bite you) A 10 char buffer is too small to fit an arbitrary `unsigned long` on any system where `unsigned long` is a 64 bit value (they need up to 20 characters, plus a `NUL` terminator). Heck, it's too small to fit the `NUL` terminator for a large 32 bit value (which would use all 10 characters on the data, plus a `NUL`), so in both cases you're risking a buffer overrun. The buffer *must* be made larger, or you need to limit the output size with `snprintf` or the like, or you need to range check the value to ensure you don't try to write it when it won't fit, anything less is undefined behavior waiting to happen.

Comment: Zeroing the buffer (`memset(temp_id, '\0', 10);`) before assigning the value worked as expected. I was under the impression that `sprintf(m_StringAccountID, "");` would initialize blank for the entire size of the buffer which is where I was wrong.

PS: Instead of assigning zeros and then initializing the value to the buffer,  `ultoa (m_pCusRateInfoStruct2->AccountID, m_StringAccountID, 10);` using ultoa without zeroing out the buffer also worked for me.